# Difficult first order ODE: $x't(x'+2)=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x't(x'+2)=x$$ I tried to transform it into homogenous equation, but that doesnt seem like a right approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$y:=x+t\qquad x=y-t$
$$t(y')^2-y=0$$
$$y'=\pm\sqrt{\frac{y}{t}}$$

Comment: How do youcome up with such tricky substitutions? Is there a general rule when to do which substitution? Or do I have to do 100s of examples to become fluent at coming up with them?

Comment: I've noticed that $x=-t$ is a solution, so I tried to "take it out" to see if the equation simplifies: I don't know if this "trick" always works, but it's worthy to try to see what happen.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: rewrite it as $x'^2t + 2x't - x = 0$ and solve the quadratic in $x'$.

Answer (score 2):

First, solve for $x'$ in terms of everything else:
\begin{align}
t(x')^2 + 2t(x') - x & = 0 \\
\therefore \qquad x' & = -1 \pm \sqrt{1 + \frac{x}{t}}.
\end{align}
This is a first-order ODE. (Well, 2 ODEs actually.)

\begin{align}
x' + 1 = \pm\sqrt{1 + \frac{x}{t}}.
\end{align}
Make a change of variable: $u = \frac{x}{t}$, so that $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d(ut)}{dt} = tu' + u$.
\begin{align}
tu' + u + 1& = \pm\sqrt{1 + u} \\
t\frac{du}{dt} & = \pm\sqrt{1 + u} - u - 1\\
\frac{du}{\pm\sqrt{1 + u} - (1 + u)} & = \frac{dt}{t} \\
-\frac{du}{\sqrt{1 + u}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + u} \mp 1}\right) & = \frac{dt}{t}
\end{align}
Now you can integrate.

Comment: Surely a hint is all that's necessary here....